Is there a British English equivalent of a "straight-A student"?
My 18-year-old private student, Italian, is taking the Cambridge Advance English exam in July. I am marking their essay which has the following phrase:

… by observing the dedication of these high-ace students.

although the meaning of the noun phrase ‘high-ace students’ can be deduced, I don't think it's idiomatic and in exams, examiners look for accuracy as well as variety in vocabulary.
I know students who are at the top of their class are sometimes called  "straight-A students" or “nerds” but I believe the former was adopted from the US while the latter is too informal for an English exam essay.
To clarify, if an exam candidate writes in American English they are not penalised as long as the essay consistently uses the same dialect.
Is there a formal British English equivalent of the phrase ‘straight-A students’? I am looking for a noun, but an adjective phrase will also do.

The term "nerd" carries other meanings in US English and has undergone some semantic shift in the past 40 years.

@Theodore  I realise it's not as derogatory as it used to be but "nerd" is not suitable for a formal essay unless it was written in scare quotes. In an informal email or article with the appropriate context, nerd is a good word to use.

I agree that "nerd" is not suitable in the context of this essay. I was pointing out that it is not strictly connected with students at the top of their class. It can be used for people narrowly focused on a topic or interest, e.g. a comic book nerd, policy nerd, etc.  See also: Nerdview.

Until a few years ago, most UK school exams were rated A, B, C etc and the term "straight A student" was common.
Although the secondary school GCSE exam has moved to a numerical grading system (where 9 is the highest mark), people still talk in terms of the old grading - you'll often hear older people ask "does that mean an 'A'?". So although that grading doesn't exist, the term "straight A student" would be understood by most people.
However, for GCSEs, the term "straight 9s" has come to be in use.
The common follow-up for GCSEs in the UK is 'A Levels', and these are still at present marked according to the system of A, B, C etc, so 'straight A student' would still be appropriate there, although there are many, many alternatives to A-Levels for students continuing their non-advanced education and not all are rated that way. I would say that "straight A student" is a pretty flexible expression that could simply mean a student that consistently gets top marks, whatever they might be.

But getting A in A level, means you are second best, since the best grade is A*

Thank you for the marking information for exams. I knew about GCSEs (which used to be called O'levels) but I didn't know that grades A, B, C, and D had been abandoned in favour of numbers. Would you know why the highest mark is 9 and not 10? This marking reminds me of IELTS, where proficiency (top marks) is awarded 9?

@Mari-LouA The current grading as of 2024 is,9 = A*, 8 = low A* / high A, 7 = A, 6 = B, 5 = low B / high C (strong pass), 4 = C (standard pass), 3 = between grades D and E, 2 = between grades E and F, 1 = between grades F and G, U = U (fail).

@Mari-LouA I was one of the first kids to sit GCSEs, and all anyone (particularly employers) wanted to know was "what is that in O levels?".

And the system of labelling an A with * (star) for excellence (1990s?) has been thrown out. That didn't last too long. I remember there was some fuss about stars being given out too liberally. :)

@Mari-LouA Well, 9 and 8 are now the equivalent of A*. But now, if they want to go higher than a 9 there's lots of logical choices.

Why aren't you saying anything about get or receive top marks? It's basically the same meaning.

@lambie Because those are verb phrases, not nouns, and the OP asked for an equivalent to a noun. Why aren't you saying anything about buttered sausage?

@Astralbee He is a straight-A student. He is a student with top marks. Oh, and "high ace" is a usual term? Who says it must be a noun? Did the Queen of Hearts decree that? It's the equivalent meaning. The OP asked for equivalent meaning, not a noun. You go on and on about UK education and don't even provide a term. Hmm. I guess that's the game here. She says an "adjective phrase will do".

@lambie Who says? The OP says. They asked for an equivalent to a noun-phrase, I've told them there is a direct equivalent ("straight 9") but "straight A" is understood anyway. And I've gone to the trouble of explaining why. Here's some reasons why "a student with top marks" is rubbish - "top" can mean the best, and lots of students can get an A or a 9, not just one. "Top" can also mean "full marks", and you don't have to get 100% to get an A or a 9 - a grade 9 at GCSE requires 130 out of 180 marks. It's a very, very poor answer.

Does this help? A quick Google search for "meaning straight-A-student" throws up nothing significant as an alternative even in online dictionaries such as Cambridge and Merriam Webster.
There is a list of 16 "synonyms" here but I don't think any of them would fit any better in the context of your student's essay.
Whilst it is agreed the phrase comes from AmE, it seems to be pretty universal now.
I guess it comes from how exams and coursework are marked. In America A,B,C,... grades are common, in the UK they are also used, but numeric grading is also widespread and in my day they told you the actual percentage you scored. So it could be country dependent.

In BrE, one sees:
a student with top marks can be an BrE cultural equivalent of a straight A student.
It can be googled and there are just too many sites to choose from.
BBC
UK

Top marks for students
Most of the newspapers focus on the triumphs of students, who scored
record highs in this year's A level results, while others offer
encouragement to those who didn't receive good news on Thursday. Now
is not the time for carping, says The Express, but rather for
celebrating the achievement of so many young people. [that's kind of a
metaphor]

This isn't:

Top marks for Perse student in major maths competition
It all added up to success for Ryan Stubbs (Year 10) as he achieved
the highest mark in the region in the Intermediate Maths Olympiad.

math competition_UK

A-level grades shake-up considered as pupils score record number of
top marks Labour warned Gavin Williamson against 'playing around with the grading system' as it emerged that ministers could consider
replacing traditional grades with numbers

The Mirror_UK

Oh please. Off with her head, as the Queen said about Alice.

That's more like it. The previous version was a bit lazy tbt.

@Mari-LouA I would have expected a native speaker from the UK to be satisfied without a ton [tonne] of examples. I don't understand the answer you chose.

The answer should help everyone, not only me. I chose Astralbee's answer because it told me something I didn't know i.e "straight 9s” and the first sentence. Whereas I know "top marks"  and also "students", so your previous answer didn't tell me anything new. Just to let you know, I am not the downvoter who seems to haunt you wherever you go, so I upvoted your post to prove it. You should notify the mods about this suspicious behaviour.

@Mari-LouA So, you noticed it too? This a.m. I noticed that I had two users removed. One on ELU and one here. What mechanism would you use to tell them? What's the best way for that type of notification (besides the chat)?

This answer is not very good because, while "a student with top marks" is a noun phrase it is not a recognised one like "straight A student". And it is misleading - "top" can mean the best, and lots of students can get an A or a 9, not just one. "Top" can also mean "full marks", and you don't have to get 100% to get an A or a 9 - a grade 9 at GCSE requires 130 out of 180 marks. So I can't support this answer at all, it feels like it was just put forward for the sake of it.

Flag one of your posts, if you noticed a string of downvotes, and in the message tell the moderators you suspect foul play. Do your best to gather some form of evidence–maybe the DV happens at a particular time of day or at the end of the week. If the DV is random there's nothing you can do, except look at your answer and ask ‘is that the best I can do?’.

@Astralbee   It is my belief that it is culturally equivalent. You don't have to agree but to say "put forward for the sake of it" is just unacceptable. Period. Yes, top can mean the best just like straight-A'means the best. Talk about hoisting oneself on one's own petard.

@Mari-LouAh, right. Thanks for reminding me of that.

I wonder if the downvoting on your answers is connected to the string of downvotes I've had on mine? Do report back any findings.

@Astralbee I have enough trouble with my own.
